# Oracle database restriction

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I would like to know if it is possible for database administrator to do something like that

1. Give read-only access to existing database.
2. However, the user should be able to create new tables (even temporary tables are fine as well).
3. User have write access to all the new temp tables created by him and these temp table disappear when the session gets closed.

I know 1st point is possible, but is it possible to give permissions specified in point 2 and 3 to someone who only has read-only access for existing database tables.

Answer (score 1):

Privileges are not granted on databases or schemas, just on objects.  You can certainly create a database user and grant that user `SELECT` access on each table in each schema of the database that you want him to access.  If new objects are created, you'd need to grant privileges on those new objects to this user.  You could then give that user the `CREATE TABLE` privilege along with appropriate quota on a tablespace in order to allow the user to create new tables.  That mostly takes care of #1 and #2.

As for #3, Oracle has no such thing as a table whose definition is local to a particular session so you can't drop the tables when the session ends.  I suppose you could create a logoff trigger that submitted a job via `dbms_job` to drop all the tables in the user's schema shortly after the user logged off.  That would be exceedingly unusual, however, so I would strongly encourage you to avoid that unless you are doing something really unusual (sqlfiddle, for example, does a lot of odd things under the covers because it is a very odd way to use an Oracle database).

Comment: Thanks Justin for the reply